# Simple Laravel named routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 4. I am trying to use named route. The following url gives a "Controller method not found" error. I will appreciate any help.

http://example.com/student/1

I understand that route order matters , and the deepest urls are supposed to go first, hence my current route.php looks :

```
Route::get('student/{id}', array('as'=>'student.practice' , 'uses'=>'StudentsController@practice'));
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::controller('students', 'StudentsController');
```

I have tried changing the order that. It makes no difference.

My StudentController does have a getPractice method.

```
public function getPractice($id)
{
    return View::make('students.practice')
    ->with('student', Student::find($id));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route like so:

```
Route::get('student/{id}', array('as'=>'student.practice' , 'uses'=>'StudentsController@getPractice'));
```

It looks like you are trying to use a mixture of RESTful and nonRESTful methods.

Comment: Thanks that worked!!


I initially experimented with naming the method in controller file. That did not worked. I think Laravel is inconsistent here. The method Route::get is supposed to be a get in the first place.


Another comment here is the the lack of proper message from Laravel/Whoops. It would help if the error message tells what method was expected and not found. 

I hope both these comments are due to my lack of knowledge being a newbie here, and laravel is better than that.

Comment: I'm please it helped. Don't forget to close the question by selecting your answer. I'd also recommend reading up on RESTful controllers. You're getting confused between the implementation of RESTful and non-RESTful controllers and their methods.